# How to reduce magnetic field between two magnetic shield sheets (silicon steel sheets)?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, magnetic-moment

I put 2 parallel silicon steel sheets between magnetic field as below:

[image]

As silicon steel has much bigger permeability than air,magnetic line will go through 2 silicon steel sheets.

What I can do to reduce magnetic field between these 2 silicon steel sheets?

Comment: What you mean by "reduce"?

Comment: @Markoul11,'reduce' means `decrease`,`attenuate`,even `remove`.For example,reduce `100ut` to `10ut`.

Answer (score 0):

The best currently material for magnetostatic shielding of strong magnetic fields (high saturation value needed) is [Giron](https://www.lessemf.com/mag-shld.html#273):

[Mu-metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal) material although it has a better magnetic permeability has however a relative small saturation value thus is suitable only for small magnetic field strength, less than one Gauss (i.e. μΤ magnetic field).

For fields one Gauss (i.e. 10 Gauss=1mT) and above go with giron.

For μΤ fields go for mu-metal.

Comment: Giron is not affordable as for high price,I choose silicon steel to shield magnetic filed.

Comment: Any mechanism to reduce magnetic field when I have only silicon steel?That's what I ask.